# A way to measure performance

Tags: haskell

Given Exercise 14 from [99 Haskell Problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions):

> (*) Duplicate the elements of a list.

Eg.:

```
*Main> dupli''' [1..10]
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10]
```

I've implemented 4 solutions:

```
{-- my first attempt --}
dupli :: [a] -> [a]
dupli [] = []
dupli (x:xs) = replicate 2 x ++ dupli xs

{-- using concatMap and replicate --}
dupli' :: [a] -> [a]
dupli' xs = concatMap (replicate 2) xs

{-- usign foldl --}
dupli'' :: [a] -> [a]
dupli'' xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ [x,x]) [] xs

{-- using foldl 2 --}
dupli''' :: [a] -> [a]
dupli''' xs = reverse $ foldl (\acc x -> x:x:acc) [] xs
```

Still, I don't know how to really measure performance .

So what's the recommended function (from the above list) in terms of performance .

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Reversing foldl usually means you could be using foldr instead. Which then means you can handle infinite lists.

Comment: Use the Criterion package, someone here will probably show you an example.

Comment: See http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2009/09/29/criterion-a-new-benchmarking-library-for-haskell/ and http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/criterion/0.5.0.5/doc/html/Criterion-Main.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As recommended you can use the criterion package. A good description is http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2009/09/29/criterion-a-new-benchmarking-library-for-haskell/.

To summarize it here and adapt it to your question, here are the steps.
Install criterion with

```
cabal install criterion -fchart
```

And then add the following to your code

```
import Criterion.Main

l = [(1::Int)..1000]

main = defaultMain [ bench "1" $ nf dupli l
                   , bench "2" $ nf dupli' l 
                   , bench "3" $ nf dupli'' l
                   , bench "4" $ nf dupli''' l
                   ]
```

You need the `nf` in order to force the evaluation of the whole result list. Otherwise you'll get just the thunk for the computation.

After that compile and run

```
ghc -O --make dupli.hs
./dupli -t png -k png
```

and you get pretty graphs of the running times of the different functions.

It turns out that `dupli'''` is the fastest from your functions but the `foldr` version that pelotom listed beats everything.

Answer (score 8):

These all seem more complicated (and/or less efficient) than they need to be. Why not just this:

```
dupli [] = []
dupli (x:xs) = x:x:(dupli xs)
```

Your last example is close to a good fold-based implementation, but you should use `foldr`, which will obviate the need to reverse the result:

```
dupli = foldr (\x xs -> x:x:xs) []
```

As for measuring performance, the "empirical approach" is [profiling](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_profile_a_Haskell_program). As Haskell programs grow in size, they can get fairly hard to reason about in terms of runtime and space complexity, and profiling is your best bet. Also, a crude but often effective empirical approach when gauging the relative complexity of two functions is to simply compare how long they each take on some sufficiently large input; e.g. time how long `length $ dupli [1..1000000]` takes and compare it to `dupli''`, etc.

But for a program this small it shouldn't be too hard to figure out the runtime complexity of the algorithm based on your knowledge of the data structure(s) in question--in this case, lists. Here's a tip: any time you use concatenation (`x ++ y`), the runtime complexity is O(`length x`). If concatenation is used inside of a recursive algorithm operating on all the elements of a list of size *n*, you will essentially have an O(*n* ^2) algorithm. Both examples I gave, and your last example, are O(*n*), because the only operation used inside the recursive definition is `(:)`, which is O(1).

Comment: Just for fun, here's an inscrutable point-free version! `dupli = foldr (liftA2 (.) (:) (:)) []` \*ducks\*